# No display after wake up. Using 14.04.1 + xfce4

Tags: laptop, suspend, xfce

Basic info:
Completely fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.1 on an HP pavilion g4-1303au laptop, by bootable USB. ISO image was downloaded on 05 September, 2014 through torrent acquired from [the official Ubuntu website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads). Installed xfce by:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

Issue:
Display doesn't get powered on when waking up from suspend, regardless of how the system was suspended(lid close or 'suspend' option in GUI), or which session (Unity or xfce) is running. The system runs perfectly fine, other than the screen being off. I'm able to log in, use the mouse to click on objects, run applications, and more; just without seeing what is happening.

Solutions attempted:

1. System Update
2. Uninstalled xscreensaver, then installed light-locker, then toggled and applied 'Lock on suspend' setting twice
3. Uninstalled light-locker, installed xscreensaver
4. Opened tty1 from the blacked out screen, logged in, and restarted the lightdm service
5. Set up a keyboard shortcut to run the following command on wake up, as described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xubuntu-default-settings/+bug/1303736/comments/11)

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1366x768 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output VGA1 --off
   ```

System information:
RAM: 6GB
Processor: AMD A4 APU
Video Card: AMD HD6480G

I'm at my wit's end with this issue, and would greatly appreciate any help.

P.S. : In general usage, the application finder in xfce takes up to a few minutes to launch, while the File Manager launches immediately. Is this affecting everyone?